# angular controller undefined only on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, iife

I don't manage to get why the following doesn't works **only on Firefox** (it works perfectly on Google Chrome and IE11) :

index.js :

```
  when("/d2d/", {
    templateUrl: "modules/d2d/d2d.view.html",
    controller: "D2DCtrl",
    controllerAs: "vm"
  }).
```

controller :

```
(function() {

  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("app.d2d")
    .controller("D2DCtrl", D2DCtrl);

  D2DCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$log", "myService"];

  function D2DCtrl($scope, $log, myService) {
      var vm = this;
      ...

  }
})();
```

controller

I got this error on view opening :

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=D2DCtrl&p1=not%20a1,#QNAN0unction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue. I will post it here because it could help others.

The origin of the issue was the use of the ES6 "let" keyword inside the controller, which can't be used in Mozilla Firefox 43 without this :

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7" src="app.js"></script>
```

EDIT: adding this element, it doesn't work anymore on Google Chrome...